# Ethertype Field in IEEE 802.1Q tagged frame

Tags: vlan

It is a basic but a bit confusing question for me .I hope It is not going to be confusing anymore after being suggested/guided from all of you.

In 802.1q tagged frame  offset[12] is the TPID which is EherType in untagged frame.

If I have to look at the Ethertype field in a Tagged frame.Which one i should take--TPID or Ethertype/Size field which is at offset[15] in tagged frame.

What is the significance of Ehertype field in Tagged frame???

Answer (score 0):

The TPID in an 802.1q frames is just the constant 0x8100. Its purpose is to identify the frame as a tagged frame to devices that support 802.1q (e.g. VLAN aware switches).

If you imagine a frame being received on an untagged port of a switch and forwarded on a tagged one, the two bytes of the VLAN header are inserted before the original Ethertype.

Most likely what you want is:

(offset[12] == 0x8100) ? offset[16] : offset[12]